# how to get automatic break on select-dropdown (BootstrapVue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

This project is created with `BootstrapVue`.

I have following problem: I have a select with multiple selections. It's responsive and it's working on full screen but when I display it on mobile devices I'm not able to see the complete `selection text`.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

***Template***

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-12">
  <b-form-select v-model="example">
    <option v-for="item in array" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.text}}
    </option>
  </b-form-select>
</div>
```

How can I get an automatic break when it's needed or useful? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot get a 2-line select on a native web UI component. Maybe if it's has a prop doing so, but looking at [the doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#component-reference), it doesn't look like it's possible. You could probably truncate it on mobile or highlight it in another way.

Comment: yeah I haven't found something either. But thanks for responding!

Comment: @B0BBY As per the issue posted on github, Selects are generally hard to style because each browser seems to handle them differently. Mobile browsers especially. I think your best bet to do this would be to use a normal dropdown and "emulate" it as a select.